# Do you know a collectionwise normal topological vector space that is not paracompact?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I am looking for an example of a collectionwise normal topological vector space that is not paracompact. Any idea about it?

Answer (score 4):

$C_p(L(\aleph_1))$, where $L(\aleph_1)$ is the one-point Lindelöfication of a discrete space of size $\aleph_1$ (add a point $\infty$ with co-countable neighbourhoods), and $C_p(X)$ is the space of continuous real-valued functions on a space $X$, in the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^X$, this is indeed a TVS.

This example is discussed on page 113 of the book General Topology III, in the Encyclopedia of Mathematical Sciences series (volume 51). All spaces of the form $C_p(X)$, for Tychonoff $X$, are ccc, (as dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}^X$) and if they are normal, they are collectionwise normal (due to Reznichenko), so it's natural to look for examples there.

This space is not paracompact because for a ccc space like $C_p(X)$ paracompact is equivalent to being Lindelöf, and $C_p(L(\aleph_1))$ contains the $\Sigma$-product of copies of $[0,1]$ as a natural closed subspace (take all $f$ with all values in $[0,1]$ and $f(\infty)=0$), and this $\Sigma$-product is ccc and countably compact, but not compact (so not Lindelöf, and thus not paracompact).

I later saw it is also discussed [here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2014/05/01/an-example-of-a-normal-but-not-lindelof-cpx/) as well, with full proofs and links.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This is wrong, because I managed to miss *vector space* when reading the question. I’m leaving it for now to make sure that the OP sees my last comment.

One of the simplest examples is $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal (viewed as the set of all countable ordinals) with the order topology; for a discussion of some of its properties see [this post](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/the-first-uncountable-ordinal/) to Dan Ma’s Topology Blog. It’s a linearly ordered space with the order topology, so it’s hereditarily collectionwise normal, but it’s not paracompact. For another proof that $\omega_1$ is collectionwise normal see [this post](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/collectionwise-normal/) to the same blog.

[Henno Brandsma’s](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4280/henno-brandsma) answer to [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78975/ccc-collectionwise-normality-paracompact) gives another example.

Comment: I know about this example but is the ordinal space that you mentioned a topological vector space ?

Comment: @Rnst: Sorry: for some reason I missed the vector space part. The second example in Henno’s MO answer should work.

Comment: I assume that you mean the S right? How can I define the appropriate (with the topology) vector space in this example ?

Comment: @Rnst: No, I mean the **second** example, $C_p(L(\aleph_1))$.